How can I specify an arrow from a distant bond to another bond in chemfig
I have an issue regarding regarding using Chemfig to display an electron movement arrow from a distant bond to another. I have tried every possible arrangement of arguments but not found a solution. I am trying to display the Grignard-Mechanism. This is the referernce image.
and for the hexagonal intermediate state I have figured out this much
\setchemfig{debug=true}
\schemestart
\chemleft[
\chemfig{O(-[@{a2}::30,,,,dash bond]@{d1}Mg?[a](-[::60]Br))=[@{a1}::270](<[::-40]*6(=-=-=-))(<:[::-80](*6(=-=-=-)))(-[@{b2}::60,,,,dash bond]([::-60]*6((-[@{b1}::120,,,,dash bond]Mg(-[@{d2}::60,,,,dash bond]([::-60]*6(=?[a,,,,dash bond]-=-=-)))(-[::-60]Br))=-=-=-)))}
\chemright]
\arrow{->[\footnotesize\text{- }\chemfig{C_6H_5-MgBr}]}[,2]
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw(a1).. controls +(45:5mm) and +(-90:5mm).. (a2);}
\chemmove{\draw(b1).. controls +(90:3mm) and +(60:3mm).. (b2);}
\chemmove{\draw(d1).. controls +(-90:3mm) and +(180:7mm).. (d2);}

But I am not able to attach the arrow to the distant bond(drawn using ?[a]) between Magnesium on the top and the benzol ring. Where should I insert the @{d1} parameter? Am I missing something else?
I have tried rearranging the @{d1} parameter without any success. It should belong into the [a,,,,dash bond] bracket, but this just throws a syntax error when putting anywhere within the commas.
Also the style for dash bond is specified here
\newcommand*{\bondboldwidth}{0.22832 em}
\newcommand*{\bondhashlength}{0.25737 em}

\tikzset{
  bold bond/.style = {line width = \bondboldwidth},
  dash bond/.style =
    {dash pattern = on \bondhashlength off \bondhashlength},
  hash bond/.style =
    {
      dash pattern = on \bondwidth off \bondhashlength,
      line width   = \bondboldwidth
    },
}

This is how it looks like at the moment


Please, can you post an image of what the final image should look like?
"the "dash bond" command does not exist in ChemFig, there is "dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt"

My bad. Seems like I have forgotten to add the link to the image. I have used a custom tikz style for the dash bond although I don't reckon there is any diffference between that and the dash pattern

Don't use distant bonds, use a common bond, and put @{d1} in this bond. Not all commands work on distant bonds
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    

%\setchemfig{debug=true}
\schemestart
\chemleft[
\chemfig{O(-[@{a2}::30,,,,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt]Mg(-[::60]Br))=[@{a1}::270](<[::-40]*6(=-=-=-))(<:[::-110](*6(=-=-=-)))(-[@{b2}::60,,,,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt]([::-60]*6((-[@{b1}::120,,,,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt]Mg(-[@{d2}::60,,,,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt]([::-60]*6((-[@{d1}:150,.7,,,,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt])=-=-=-)))(-[::-60]Br))=-=-=-)))}
\chemright]
\arrow{->[\chemfig{C_6H_5-MgBr}]}[,2]
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw(a1).. controls +(45:5mm) and +(-90:5mm).. (a2);}
\chemmove{\draw(b1).. controls +(90:3mm) and +(60:3mm).. (b2);}
\chemmove{\draw(d1).. controls +(-90:3mm) and +(180:7mm).. (d2);}

\end{document}


Another code:
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemleft[
\chemfig{(<:[:150]*6(=-=-=-))(<[:220]*6(=-=-=-))*6([:30]-[@{d2},,,,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt]*6([:-90]=-=-=-)-[@{d1},,,,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt]Mg(-Br)-[@{b2},,,,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt]*6([:30]=-=-=-)-[@{b1},,,,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt]Mg(-Br)-[@{a2},,,,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt]O=[@{a1}])}
\chemright]
\schemestop
\chemmove{
    \draw[red,shorten <= 3pt,shorten >= 1pt](a1).. controls +(0:5mm) and +(-60:5mm).. (a2);
          \draw[red,shorten <= 1pt,shorten >= 1pt](b1).. controls +(240:3mm) and +(180:5mm).. (b2);
          \draw[red,shorten <= 1pt,shorten >= 1pt](d1).. controls +(120:5mm) and +(60:5mm).. (d2);
        }
\end{document}



Thank you for the hint. I will do that on next occasion. Chemfig really is something one has to get used to. Appreciate your help
